# How to make Amazon EC2 not cause SSL invalid error in browser

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, domain-name

I use SSL certificate for a web site I set up in Amazon EC2 Machine Instance. The SSL certificate is for one domain name, which is not public DNS for the Amazon Machine Instance. The browser always complains the mismatch in the domain name because it compares the domain name of the SSL certificate to the Amazon public DNS.

How can I set up not to cause this problem?

I tried both domain name forwarding and A Record setting.

Maybe it's because I'm not so familiar with Amazon EC2 and I haven't configured domain name correctly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

The browser compares the domain name that you've typed in the address bar with the domain name in the certificate. If they're different then there's an error: that's by design.

The way to "fix" this is to buy a certificate for whatever domain name you type into the browser to get to the EC2 instance: mywebsite.com, not ec2-x-y-z.compute-1.amazonaws.com or whatever...

Answer (score 0):

After that the instance has an IP you can setup a domain name with it if you want. The easiest way is you can use through a DNS service like EveryDNS. Just provide your domain name registrar with EveryDNS’s domain name servers, create an EveryDNS account, add your domain and create an A record with your newly associated EC2 instance IP address.

after that you have to get a certificate for that domain name.If you do these steps and still having problems pls let me know.

also you can read [here](http://paulstamatiou.com/how-to-getting-started-with-amazon-ec2) for further details.

and i faced same problem before you can check the [amazon forums](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/message.jspa?messageID=137755) for the exact answer